# I can't find the file "my.cnf" or "my.ini"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed version 8 of MySQL and I can't find the configuration file

I was reading and everyone says that it is inside the "MySQL Server x.0" folder, but in my case it does not appear, neither inside the "etc" or "bin" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are on Windows because of the "MySQL Server x.0" folder name (on Mac & Linux, this folder name does not contain spaces by default).

No configuration file is created after a standard installation. You *may* create one if you have the need to specify any options. Otherwise every option has a default setting built into the MySQL Server.

On Windows, the MySQL Server searches several locations for the configuration file, so you can put the file in any of those locations.

See documentation for a list of the locations the server searches for the configuration file on Windows:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-create-option-file.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Remember that after you edit the configuration file, you need to restart the MySQL Server. It reads the configuration options only when the server starts.

Comment: Sorry for my inexpertice, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How I found mine was like this;

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep my.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows my.ini file will be auto generated when you install MySQL server. It will be located in a hidden directory **ProgramData**.

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
```

In order to view these files you may need to show hidden items. To do that

Open file explorer > View > Tick Hidden Items